# How to cancel Xbox Gold subscription without sign in details?

Tags: xbox-network

My Xbox Gold membership is years old, I no longer have the login details (email address is likely deactivated) and struggling to get a customer number without the sign in details to cancel it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant connect to the account and can't get through with customer service, I think your only option would be to call the credit card company or other thing that is paying for the subscription and see if they have options where you can force stop regular payments to an account.

Pretty sure they can do so that any payments to MICROSOFT OF AMERICA INC will be blocked, and then the XBL subscription will end because the payment will bounce.

Fees may apply, check beforehand.